# MySQL returns all rows with empty string as where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, casting

I discovered this problem while debugging CodeIgniter active record as shown below:

```
$this->db->from("table_name");
$this->db->where("field_name", "");
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` = 0;  // Returns all rows in table
```

Even though the empty string is cast to 0, we expect an empty result since `table_name`.`field_name` is full of non-empty string values.  However, I get the entire table from this query.  Anyone understand why?  This is not intuitive at all.

I tried the query without the cast to 0 and it works:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` = "";  // Empty result
```

Why the cast to 0?

---

EDIT: The same cast to 0 happens with this alternative CodeIgniter syntax:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name = ?', array(""));
```

Comment: What db driver are you using? field type? I suspect is part of the Active Record's parametrization, you could look into its core

Comment: Might take a quick look at the `where` function in the db library. could be a simple conditional that you can fix with an overwrite.

Comment: if that field_name field is a char/varchar, those will get cast to ints as well, and most likely map to 0, so you're still matching the whole table.

Comment: Since field_name is `varchar` MYSQL expects a string on both side of the comparison. Now you have integer on the right side, it makes mysql to evaluate left hand side as integer, resulting ultimate condition as `0=0`

Comment: Thanks guys.  I see why the comparison with 0 will yield all results.  That said, my remaining question is: why the cast to 0?  That's the most unintuitive part and the part that breaks the expected behavior.  Perhaps we can call this a bug with CodeIgniter

Answer (score 1):

Try using following, if you are using `codeigniter`:

```
$this->db->where("field_name = ''");
```

Comment: I'm not directly searching for "", but a $variable which could be an empty string.  It makes sense to take advantage of codeigniter's native escaping rather than inserting the variable directly into the string.